# Docker with Windows auth to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, docker, sqlalchemy

I need to connect to SQL Server from inside Python sript, that's running in docker.

I have this string to connect to this server from script, but it works only when i coonect from windows without docker.

```
string = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=SRV-DAT-DB06;DATABASE=;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES"
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(string)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}')
```

Thats error i have when i use docker.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Any ideas?

I have no passwords and users to this SQl Server. It works from inside Windows